# Tweet button doesn't work properly. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am building a Random quote machine. I have a tweet button to share the quote. It works, but only after I click "Generate Quote" button first. If I click "tweet" straight after the page is loaded - it doesn't work. 
I know it is happening because my  `$(".twitter-share-button").attr("href", "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + thisQuote);` code is within the `$("#gen").on("click", function(){`,  but I don't know how to remove it outside this function.

When I place it outside it doesn't work, because the value to the `thisQuote` var is passed within `$("#gen").on("click", function(){`

When I try to put all the code before `$("#gen").on("click", function(){` it stops working.

How do I order the functions properly in this case?

My pen: http://codepen.io/s4ek1389/pen/zZGNWw?editors=1010

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var thisQuote = "";
   $("#gen").on("click", function(){

    $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function(json) {



    var author = "";
   var quote = "";

   $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});

  json.forEach(function(val){
    author+= val.title;    
   quote+= val.content;
    var shortQuote = quote.slice(3,-5);
 thisQuote = shortQuote + " - " + author; 

 $("#author").html(author);
  $("#mainquote").html(quote);
  })

     $(".twitter-share-button").attr("href", "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + thisQuote);


});

  });    


  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to retrieve the random quote when the page is finished loading instead of only when the button is clicked.

I've made a separated method so it's easier to read and maintain.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var thisQuote = "";

    getRandomQuote();

    $("#gen").on("click", function () {
        getRandomQuote();
    });

    function getRandomQuote() {
        $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function (json) {

            var author = "";
            var quote = "";

            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

            json.forEach(function (val) {
                author += val.title;
                quote += val.content;
                var shortQuote = quote.slice(3, -5);
                thisQuote = shortQuote + " - " + author;

                $("#author").html(author);
                $("#mainquote").html(quote);
            })

            $(".twitter-share-button").attr("href", "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + thisQuote);
        });
    }

});
```

CodePen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PpzvvP

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger a click the first time to assign the href to your "tweet button"

```
$("#gen").trigger("click");
```

http://codepen.io/sassoli/pen/yMJWZo

if you need to start with the default sentence of William Shakespeare, instead you can add this

http://codepen.io/sassoli/pen/OpXYGM

```
 $(".twitter-share-button").attr("href", "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + $("#mainquote").text()+ " - "+ $("#author").text());
```